# How to pass multiple passwords to a java process

Tags: java, process

I'm using Runtime to execute a command, which accepts password twice (like : enter password, verify password). I'm using the following code. The problem I'm facing is programs hangs, because it is waiting for verify password. 1st password is getting passed properly (I verfied by removing verify password from my command and in the java code and it works), verify password is not getting passed to the command and command waits for the verify password indefinately. Please let me know if anyone has any sugestions.

```
try
    {
      runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      process = runtime.exec("<<my command>>"");
      String inLine = "";
      String errLine = "";
      StringBuffer inBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      StringBuffer errBuffer = new StringBuffer();

      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());
      pw.print("<<password>>"+"\n");
      pw.print("<<verify password>>"+"\n");
      pw.flush();

      BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
              process.getInputStream()));
      BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
              process.getErrorStream()));

      while ((inLine = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
          inBuffer = inBuffer.append(inLine + "\n");
      }
      stdin.close();
      System.out.println("Output messages of cmd " + inBuffer.toString());

      while ((errLine = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
          errBuffer = errBuffer.append(errLine + "\n");
      }
      stderr.close();
      System.out.println("Error messages of cmd " + errBuffer.toString());

      process.waitFor();
      int exitCode = process.exitValue();
      System.out.println("cmd " + " exited with code " + exitCode);


    }
```

Comment: Does the process output anything to console before you are required to write a password?

Comment: No, It does not output anything to console before I write password

Comment: So, if you ran the program from the command line, it would not display any kind of prompt at all??

Comment: I misinterpreted your earlier question, If we run the command directly on command line it prompts for password and verify password

Answer (score 0):

Both `while ((inLine = stdin.readLine()) != null) {` and `while ((errLine = stderr.readLine()) != null) {` will block your main thread until data is available. It could be your command is spitting something out into stderr but you can't see it because your main thread got blocked on stdin read loop

It's better to consume stdin and stderr using a separate thread, you can debug your code easier

Answer (score 0):

Try using these things:

```
System.out.println("<<password>>");
String pw;
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          System.in));
while ((pw = stdin.readLine()) != null){ //Waits for a reply for the first password
    if (pw != ""){
        break; //This breaks the loop, and 'pw' is the password entered.
    }
}
```

Repeat that for the

> << verifypassword >>

and change the variables. That should work!

Here's the verifypassword

```
System.out.println("<<verifypassword>>");
String pw2;
BufferedReader stdin2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          System.in));
while ((pw2 = stdin2.readLine()) != null){ //Waits for a reply for the first password
    if (pw2 != ""){
        break; //This breaks the loop, and 'pw' is the password entered.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code given above seems to be for reading the password from command line. In my case the command I'm executing using RunTime is execpecting password twice (password & verify password), and I want pass the values to the process. When I do this, first password is getting read by the process and it waits for verify password (even though I have written password twice to the process)

 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());
      pw.print("<<password>>"+"\n");
      pw.print("<<verify password>>"+"\n");
      pw.flush();

Comment: So, what you want is a program executing a program with a password passed as parameters?